# I cannot get spring tools suite to run my program

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

[36mo.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: It's a MySQL permissions issue.  You aren't allowed to connect to the database.  Very bad idea to use the root password, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had spring and tomcat connected previously using the exact setup.  Once my computer crashed I lost all files.  After reinstalling everything, the Spring boot will not connect.

Comment: You ought to be using a source code management system like Subversion or Git.  You wouldn't lose everything that way.  Sorry, start again.  You won't get anywhere by insisting "I'm right; it should work."  Sounds like you didn't understand what you did in the first place.

Comment: I will admit I am a novice. I am enrolled in a full stack online teaching environment.  I followed the video the way it was presented using the tools the instructor advised.  As mentioned before I had it up and running until the computer crash.

Comment: You need to learn more.  Sorry, I don't think I'll be able to bail you out.  Start again.

Comment: Thanks, that would probably be my best bet at this point.

Comment: Found the problem.  I had an extra space after username 'root'.